# Facebook SDK iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook, sdk

Раньше можно было использовать следующую функцию при инициализации приложения:

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)
```

В Swift 3 `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` отсутствует в принципе.

Может знаете как Swift 3 подружить с SDK от Facebook?

SDK нужна для авторизации и получения id, имя, дату рождения, email по возможности и конечно токен.

Comment: Побойтесь бога, как может отсутствовать didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. И главное при чем тут свифт - этот класс/метод никакой стороной от свифта не зависит

Answer (score 2):

Функция никуда не исчезала, оно просто немного видоизменилась =)

Раньше было так:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)
-> Bool {return true}
```

Сейчас так:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil)
-> Bool {return true}
```

Comment: Теперь данный метод ничего не возвращает, и параметр launchOptions отсутствует

Comment: жалко, комментарии минусовать нельзя.